# Are you ready to lose your 5 teeth but achieve your goal? Is "ready" a well-chosen adjective? What about the but clause?

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to make a sentence which asks how far a person is willing to go to achieve a goal. I wrote:

Anytime you want to make sure that you are serious enough about your dream, ask yourself:

> Are you ready to lose your 5 teeth but achieve your goal.

I have two problems with this self made sentence.

1. Is "ready" a good adjective, because I think "ready" is usually used in different type of sentences like "Are you ready for the trip?"
2. I am not sure about the "but achieve to your goal" part. Is it even grammatical at the first place, put aside being idiomatic!

Comment: "Are you ready to lose your 5 teeth **to** achieve your goal".

Comment: Is "lose your five teeth"  a saying in your native language? Is there some significance to 5?  I ask because **your five teeth** is somewhat odd to me. Your **front** teeth would be idiomatic.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo No, I just put the number, the bigger the number is, the more serious that may sound!

Comment: Then it would be **five of your teeth**.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - unless most of them have already fallen out and you only have 5 teeth left! :-D

Comment: @greenonline: As Michael "The Koan" Cohen might say, "Are you ready to lose all the teeth you still don't have?"

Comment: I was going to comment to say that 'your teeth' is more comprehensive and flows much better as an expression... on reflection, though, the weirdness of specifying 'five' *does* make this odd expression more impactful.

Comment: Still a strange thing to compare teeth to goals. If this came up in conversation, I think I'd just find an excuse to leave and get a different guru/hockey coach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although **ready** and **prepared** are close synonyms, they seem to me to have a difference in emphasis here:

**ready** implies that those teeth  stand a very good chance of being knocked out. They might well be lost.  It's almost guaranteed.

Are you **prepared** to lose...  implies that those teeth *may* be lost. You could lose them.  There is some risk.

> Would you risk your front teeth...

is less forceful, less fanatical than **are you ready to lose**.

So, depending on the degree of fanaticism and commitment required, you might choose one or the other.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer, have you any suggestion for the but-clause? I mean, would you suggest the correct ''but-clause". I mean, is it possible to write an idiomatic sentence with "but"?

Comment: I think the idea you mean to express with **but** could be expressed by the phrase ***if that's what it would take** to achieve your goal*. *Would you risk your front teeth if that's what it would take to achieve your goal?*

Answer (score 7):

In the two phrases "Are you ready to lose.." and "Are you ready for..", ready is being used as an adjective.  When used this way, ready has two main definitions:

> 1. To be willing to do something.
> 2. To be prepared for an action or event.

You are using ready in the first sense, while being ready for a trip is using it in the second sense.

You should not say, "Are you ready to lose your 5 teeth...", as this implies that the person only has 5 teeth to lose. It would be better to say, "Are you ready to lose five of your teeth...".

Almost all style guides recommend that the numbers from one to nine be written as words instead of numbers, so you should say "five" instead of "5".

On the whole I think that your question may be better phrased as:

> Would you be willing to lose five of your teeth if it meant that you would be able to achieve your goal?

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer, I liked the fact that you mentioned that implication.

Comment: Hmm. I always thought most style guides recommended writing numbers from one to twelve in words

Comment: That was an excellent answer up to the rephrase, which is not a linguistic formulation that a human who is standard would articulate to a listener who is also assumed to be a human who is standard. The original question (less the 'your 5') was much more natural and better expressed.

Comment: `It would be better to say, "Are you ready to lose five of your teeth..."` "Are you ready to lose five teeth" would already remove the implication that they only have 5 teeth. "Your" (by itself) suggests that the five teeth are a complete set. (Note: your answer is fully correct; I'm just offering the _smallest_ change from OP's original that already fixes the issue)

Comment: @somebody  For some style guides the recommendation is for numbers from one to nine, others say one to ten, others say one to twelve, and others still say one to one hundred. Although I only mentioned 'style guides', I am not just referring to official, published style guides such as the Chicago Manual of Style, but also house styles for magazines, universities and corporations, etc. I only chose to say 'one to nine' because it is the lowest range that is agreed to by all of the style guides that I have used.